# adding more than one middleware to controller in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a function which I want to access by two different guards, if either of the user or admin is logged in he/she can access that function

If I go like this than it requires both people (user and admin) to be logged in to access the function

```
class HomeController  extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth')->only('showABC');
            $this->middleware('auth:hr');
    }
}
```

But I want that if any of two types is logged in he/she can access showABC method. 
I need to use something like "OR" rather than "AND"

Comment: I can help you. But I need some more information: where you have written above mentioned lines?

Comment: thanks, this is in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to make your own middleware where you can write your authentication code in the default method `handle`. And then you need to call only that middleware to get either of the users authenticated.

Make one middleware inside `app/Http/Middleware/CustomAuthentiation.php`
And write your logic there, something like this snippet:

```
class CustomAuthentiation
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        // Write your authentication code here and then in last lines, if all is good, forward the execution ahead. Like :
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then add it to `$routeMiddleware` array in Kernel.php file at `app/Http/Kernel.php` like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'myAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomAuthentiation::class  // Here is your middleware..
        ];
```

Then you can bind this middleware in your `routes/web.php` like this:

```
Route::middleware('myAuth')->post('login', 'LoginController@LoginUser');
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I found a way from your code now I am checking guard before eaxch function like: 

if (Auth::guard('hr')->check() || Auth::guard('web')->check()) { //my func}

Comment: Great, but are you checking this `if` condition in your controller?

Comment: yes in each function where I require access for both of the users